# Idea to Modulate a Laser with a 1/4 Wave Plate

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, polarization

Procedure:
Take a linear polarized red laser beam and send it through a 1/4 wave plate to create elliptically polarized light. Then send this elliptical polarized light through a linear polarized filter. Will the exiting light be modulated?
My theory is that the elliptical polarization takes time to complete a rotation. I imagine this to be like a rotating hand of a clock. The linear filter will allow the transmission light at only a specific time on the clock, thus the light exiting the filter will be modulated in the nano second range.
My question: Will this produce modulated laser light, and will it be measurable with a 10ns photodiode and an oscillolscope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. We can decompose the elliptical polarization into the basis of the linear polarizer, say, with independent axes $x$ and $y$. In general, the elliptical wave is just a linear combination of sinusoids in those directions with arbitrary amplitudes and phases. The effect of the polarizer is to zero one of these terms, say the one in the $y$ direction. Then you have remaining a simple sinusoid polarized in $x$ with its corresponding amplitude and phase.

Comment: @Lambda I forgot to mention that I applaud your outside-the-box thinking. Keep it up, even if they’re not all going to work out!

Comment: @Lambda, I also forgot to mention that the period of a red laser beam oscillation will be in the timescale of *femto*seconds, not nanoseconds—too fast to measure directly with an oscilloscope or spectrum analyzer.